# content displayed out of expandable div image

Tags: html, css

When I tried to add content dynamically,div image is expanding,but the content is displaying outside the image.

```
<div  class="sentcontainer"  >
    <table style="margin-left:6%;">
        <td>if the content is long,going out og image</td>
    </table>           
</div>
```

```css
.sentcontainer
{
     background-image: url("../images/sent.png");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        margin-right: -8%;
        overflow:auto;
}
```

please me to get through.

Comment: Where is your `tr` (*Table Row*) tag?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan And the `img` too?!

Comment: ...And how you exactly add your content and where? I think you should add the missing tag first.

Comment: I think he thought about the background image. @jyoti doddagoudar: please create a jsfiddle with image with absolute path.

Comment: @all Please stop asking for *fiddles* when all you have is in Question. (For those who don't know how to create one: http://jsbin.com/dupofi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Use padding instead of strange -/+ % margins and add the missing `<tr>` tag:

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/dupofi/3/edit)**